# Where did my crontab go?

Tags: command-line, scripts, cron

I was using `crontab -e` to make a cronjob, which I saved.

I then closed it, and typed in `crontab -e` again, but my cron job isn't there? It looks like it might be opening a new file each time.

How can I find that cron job to stop it from firing?

Comment: Are you sure you run both commands as same user?

Comment: Yeah i typed it in once, closed it, and typed it in again straight after

Comment: What commands you have run exactly?

Comment: It opens the file: `/tmp/crontab.[RANDOM 6 CHARACTERS]/crontab`

Comment: I just ran `crontab -e`

Answer (score 1):

Personal crontabs are stored in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/${USER}`.  These files should always be edited via `crontab -e`, but you can `sudo rm` one if it is causing problems.  It should be recreated the next time that user uses `crontab -e` *and* commits.

Comment: How come this answers the basic question which is where did the crontab go?

Comment: @heemayl, it may answer the OP's question "[h]ow can I find that cron job to stop it firing?", slightly different than the question he gave in the title.

Comment: Downvote removed, again we need to sort out the reason given OP is right..

Comment: I tried to look in that folder, got a permission denied so I changed the permissions. However, the folder is empty?

Comment: (1) Don't change permissions on that folder (2) If there is no personal crontab file, are you sure that the job *is* firing?  Or are you just concerned that it might?

Comment: Do you know the permissions to change it back? And i'm pretty sure it will be firing

Comment: Wait, i definitely saved it, but running `crontab -l` or `crontab -r` returns `no crontab for pi`

Comment: `sudo chmod 1730 /var/spool/cron/crontabs` should restore appropriate permissions.